# Responsive Bootstrap's Javascripts Carousel height 100%

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set bootstrap's js [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) to a responsive height of 100%.

Currently, I have the carousel as the entire background until it hits a screen size of 1020px .

```
     .carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
    }
```

Here's my carousel...

When the screen size hits 1020px the carousel starts to shrink, showing the body background color.

Like so...
[image]

I need the image to have a height of 100% when it hits responsive sizes.

Comment: So to have `height: 100%` work on something, its parent needs to have an explicit height set (in pixels) OR all of its parents need to have `height: 100%` set on them, going back to the body tag. If neither of those sound like an option, making the image a background image would make this really easy to do.

Comment: This did the trick I had to add `.carousel-inner  {height: 100%;} .carousel-inner > .item {height:100%;}`  Thank you for the insight!